# jQuery hasClass and if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, mutation-observers

I'm having issues trying to get this code to run properly. 
I have a div element called .collapsible-menu and I need to change its z-index when it becomes active. 
When the menu is clicked the class, 'menu-active' is added to the body through some other js.

This is what I have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  if ($("body").hasClass('menu-active')) {
     $(".collapsible-menu").css("zIndex", 100);
  } else {
     $(".collapsible-menu").css("zIndex", 3);
  }
});
```

Does this require me to use a mutation observation due to the class being added in after the documents been loaded? If so, is this on the right path?

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
      mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
         if ($("body").hasClass('menu-active')) {
            $(".collapsible-menu").css("zIndex", 100);
         } else {
            $(".collapsible-menu").css("zIndex", 3);
         }
         console.log(mutation.type);
     });    
});
```

Comment: `'` missing. Typo in the question or in your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use CSS.

```
.collapsible-menu{
   z-index: 3;
}
.menu-active .collapsible-menu{
   z-index: 100;
}
```

If you can do something using the **CSS**, it is almost always **better solution** than using **JavaScript**

Comment: Holy crap i'm an idiot, I instantly went the JS route. Thanks again.